# How to position my Silverlight OOB window to the bottom right corner of the desktop?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

I'm trying to move an Out-of-browser (OOB) Silverlight app to the bottom right corner, above the systray. The app is sized to 160x100.

I just can't get it close enough to the bottom of the screen.  The moment I set the "Top" property above a certain value, it is just ignored.

For example in my App.xaml.cs:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
    if (App.Current.HasElevatedPermissions &&
        App.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
    {
        Window w = App.Current.MainWindow;
        w.Width = 160;
        w.Height = 100;
        w.Left = 1108;
        // Up to this point the above all works ok.
        w.Top = 603; // This is ignored if over 602!
    }
}
```

Setting App.Current.MainWindow.Top is ignored if the value is greater than 602 for Window Style='Default', or greater than 640 for Window Style='No Border'.

If I set the 'Top' value above 603 it just silently defaults to the Top specified in the Out-Of-Browser Settings dialog in the Project settings (50 in my case).  No exception is thrown.

The 'Left' property doesn't seem to have this problem: I can set Left to move the window right up the right-hand side of the screen.

I'm using Windows XP SP3 and Silverlight 4.0 / VS2010. I've checked the 'Require elevated trust when running outside the browser' box.

Any reason why I can't move my window further down on the screen?

Is there any other way to make my window appear to be "docked" to the bottom right of the screen?

Thanks!

**Update:**
I should have mentioned:

- I have checked the 'Set window location manually' box in the 'Out-of-Browser Settings' dialog. Setting the Top/Left properties here (as opposed to in the code), the result is the same: if I set 'Top' to a value over 640 (window style='No Border') then the window is placed in the middle of the desktop, instead of at the specified coordinates.
- I don't really set the Top/Left to hardcoded values in my app -- I've done so in the code snippet above just to illustrate the issue. In the actual app, I let the user move the window, then I save the position when the app exits.
- I would like to detect the screen/desktop size, but couldn't find a way to do it in Silverlight.

Comment: You should be calculating the `Left` and `Top` values based on the size of the screen rather than hardcoding values which will need changing for different screen resolutions.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF, I should have mentioned (a) I don't hard code the Top/Left values in my app, I only did it in the code snippet above to illustrate the problem; (b) I would like to detect the screen/desktop size, but couldn't find a way to do it in Silverlight.

Comment: good point. That's a separate question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [WindowStartupLocation to Manual](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-customising-the-window.aspx).

```
<OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings>  
    <WindowSettings Title="Silverlight Application"   
                    WindowStartupLocation="Manual"  
                    Left="0"  
                    Top="0"  
                    Width="640"  
                    Height="480"/>  
  </OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings>
```

You can also access the `OutOfBrowserSettings.WindowSettings` via code behind if needed.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron! I should have mentioned that I already have the 'Set window location manually' box checked in the 'Out-of-Browser Settings' dialog.  The problem is, while I can successfully set the position of the window manually, it appears that there is a maximum for the 'Top' property (640 in my case).  Even setting Top in the Out-Of-Browser Settings doesn't solve the problem.  Also, I don't really hard code the Top/Left values in my app, the actual code simply saves the last window position in IsolatedStorage when closing the app, and then I move the window after startup.

Comment: @codeblast Are you doing something similar to this (scroll to the bottom)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.top(v=VS.95).aspx in that you save off the top/left/width/height via IsolatedStorage and restore them as such yet it does take effect? Is there a max* on any of your properties within the Window? What resolution are you running?

Comment: Hi @Aaron, yes that's exactly what I do! (Save top/left in Application_Exit and load in Application_Startup.) My resolution is 1280x800. This may be relevant but doesn't exactly describe my problem: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/192180.aspx - seems like Silverlight adds some padding to the window when manually setting Top/Left. I may just have to accept that I can't position the window too close to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Window w = App.Current.MainWindow;
    w.Width = 1;
    w.Height = 1;
    w.Left = 1108;        
    w.Top = 603; 
    w.Width = 160;
    w.Height = 100;
```

but use try catch